# How to give "only append" access to user in windows , for logging purposes

Tags: powershell, file-permissions

I have a powershell script which takes some data and dumps into a logfile whenever its executed.The script resides in single location and shortcut is distributed to all.

I want to log the events on the script when it's executed; How can I give the users only append access to the log file ; I don't want them deleting the logs; they only need to apped to that.

Please do let me know of any questions or clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the NTFS permissions on the log file.  You need to ensure that the "Create folders / append data" permission only is granted to the individuals or groups that you want to be able to only append to the log file.  That setting is in the "Advanced" portion of the permissions on the file.

[image]

Also see: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/windows-101-know-the-basics-about-ntfs-permissions/6084446

> Create Folders/Append Data: This Create Folders permission allows
>   users to create folders within a folder. (This applies to folders
>   only.) The Append Data permission allows users to make changes to the
>   end of the file, but they can't change, delete, or overwrite existing
>   data. (This applies to files only.)

Comment: Should the inheritence be disabled?

Comment: It doesn't need to be - permissions granted explicitly on a file will take precedence over inherited permissions. An explicit deny takes precedence over an inherited allow, an explicit allow takes precedence over an inherited deny, etc.

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't work for me :( http://imgur.com/a/MpTTJ

Comment: this seem to be minimal permission set for append (via command line redirection) to work: http://imgur.com/h59bZBE. My guess is that Write is actually required for appending data, but without Append permission, you can't resize the file.

Comment: @LogicDaemon: Good find. Unfortunately, this make the whole endeavor kind of useless: Once the user has write permissions, the user can just replace the complete file contents (using `>` instead of `>>`), thus effectively deleting the log. This seems to be [a limitation of command line redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56423674/87698).